# Enter-PSSession returns PSRemotingTransportException

Tags: powershell

When I try to connect to a remote server using `Enter-PSSession`, I get a `PSRemotingTransportException`. It says that the user is either unknown or associated with a wrong password.

It works with other users, and it works with this user on other servers.  The user is in the Administrator group of the remote server.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

The main problem I have is this. I have three servers: `remote1`, `remote2`, and `main`, one domain: `domain`, and two users: `user1` and `user2`.

So now I'm connected with `user1` on `main`.  The first problem is that when I use `Enter-PSSession` on `remote1`, I'm connected via `user2`:

> PS C:\Users\user1> whoami
>
> domain\user1
>
> PS C:\Users\user1> Enter-PSSession remote1
>
> [remote1]: PS C:\Users\user2\Documents> whoami
>
> domain\user2
>
> [remote1]: PS C:\Users\user2\Documents>

The second problem is that when I use `Enter-PSSession` on `remote2`, it doesn't work:

> PS C:\Users\user1> Enter-PSSession remote2
>
> Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server failed with the
>   following error message :  Access is denied. For more information, see
>   the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic. At line : 1 Char: 16
>   + Enter-PSSession <<<<  remote2
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (remote2:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed
>
> PS C:\Users\user1>

Comment: If anyone can fix that, I offer him a sandwich

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm, that sounds odd.

One possibility is that the default PSSession configuration(s) got messed up. To reset it, use the following code:

```
Get-PSSessionConfiguration -Name Microsoft.PowerShell | Unregister-PSSessionConfiguration;
```

And then run:

```
Enable-PSRemoting -Force;
```

Also, are you sure that you are using the `domain\username` format when specifying your credentials (assuming that you're specifying alternate credentials)?

Comment: It works when I specify `-Credential domain\username` but I dont understand, why ?

Comment: Hmmm, maybe the credential you're launching PowerShell as doesn't have access to the remote server? Are you launching PowerShell "as Administrator?"

Comment: No, but it works when I use another user. And it works when I try on another remote server, without specifying domain :/

Comment: Any chance there's a local user created on the machine with the same name as the domain account you're using?

Comment: There is no other user with the same name on the remote machine, it's really weird

Comment: I just figured out something. When I connect to a remote server that works, I am in the Documents folder of another user ...

Comment: Any idea ? I'm really stuck on this subject

Comment: It's possible that there is a "RunAs" account configured in the PSSessions. Use the `Get-PSSessionConfiguration` command on that server to find out. You can also run `whomai` to figure out if you're impersonating a user or not.

Comment: When I use whoami, I see that I'm connected with the wrong user, but if I use Get-PSSessionConfiguration I don't see any RunAs configured. The only thing I got is that :

Comment: Name                      PSVersion  StartupScript        Permission
----                      ---------  -------------        ----------
Microsoft.PowerShell      2.0
Microsoft.PowerShell32    2.0
microsoft.ServerManager   2.0                             BUILTIN\Administrateurs AccessAl...

Answer (score 2):

i ran into this same issue. Do you have a password on that user account? I gave mine a password and that issue went away.

hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your credentials may be cached, I faced the same issue and updated the passowords that were cached in windows using the tool here:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15574/how-do-i-clear-cached-credentials-from-my-windows-profile

Answer (score 0):

I ran into exact same issue too. I have `admin` account on my local machine at home & remote machine at work. However, since I upgraded to windows 10 at home, I switched to `@outlook.com` email to get early windows update, but I noticed that the admin account is still there albeit being masked somehow. Right now, I log into windows using `pin` that I've setup.

So the following for whatever reason won't work, even though i used to work before

```
Enter-PSSession remote -Credential admin
```

however this works

```
Enter-PSSession remote -Credential remteComputerName\admin
```

All computers are in WORKGROUP, admin account has same password in both machines

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem today where my remote user couldn't connect via powershell with Enter-pssession -ComputerName

If you run the command in a Powershell Administrator Window:

`PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-PSSessionConfiguration`

The following output appears

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-PSSessionConfiguration

Name          : microsoft.powershell
PSVersion     : 5.1
StartupScript :
RunAsUser     :
Permission    : NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE AccessAllowed, 
BUILTIN\Administrators AccessAllowed, BUILTIN\Remote Management Users AccessAllowed
```

Remote Management Users are allowed access and my remote user, wasn't explicitly assigned to that group. That remote user was defined as an Administrator and I thought that was enough. Once I added my login to the Remote Management Users group explicitly, I was able to connect with powershell.

Nothing else was required, but I did add a rule to restrict the allowed hosts to one IP address.

```
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Force -Value my.remote.ip.address
```

and restarted winrm with restart-service winrm

This is the same solution I use to allow RDP access to users not defined as administrators